# Passing Object literal in prototype changes constructor?

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = {
  sayName: function()  {
    console.log(this.name);
  },

 toString: function() {
   return "[Person " + this.name + "]";
  }
};
```

When i pass the object literal in prototype it changes the constructor property, so that it now points to `Object` instead of `Person`. Why so ? pls someone explain.

Answer (score 1):

You just set `Person.prototype` to an object. The object's `constructor` is `Object`, hence the `Person`'s constructor also becomes `Object`. What did you expect?

You can either set the properties one by one, or you can just add back the constructor property:

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = {
  sayName: function()  {
    console.log(this.name);
  },

 toString: function() {
   return "[Person " + this.name + "]";
  },

  constructor: Person
};
```

As TravisJ commented, it would probably be better to set it using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), so that we can set enumerability to false, as it is by default.

```
Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'constructor', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false, // this is the default; including as an example
    value: Person
});
```

Comment: +1 for your analysis - however, it would be best to include the constructor using Object.defineProperty so that the enum flag can be set to false as it is by default.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype by default points to an object whose property(named constructor) is the name of the invoked function.

This property basically tells from which function or parent the new object is constructed from.

When you overwrite it with a custom object literal, this piece of information is lost. Usually when a property is not found it looks up in the prototype chain and in this case it finds the constructor property all the way in "Object".You can add the constructor property back inside your literal.This way the lookup stops at the new object you have created.